# How to ajaxify cart items and total

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a website and I want to update its cart items and total via ajax every time someone clicks on "add to cart". I am using the code below in my wordpress's function.php

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','sk_wcmenucart', 10, 2);
function sk_wcmenucart($menu, $args) {

    // Check if WooCommerce is active and add a new item to a menu assigned to Primary Navigation Menu location
    if ( !in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) || 'primary' !== $args->theme_location )
        return $menu;

    ob_start();
        global $woocommerce;
        $viewing_cart = __('View your shopping cart', 'your-theme-slug');
        $start_shopping = __('Start shopping', 'your-theme-slug');
        $cart_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url();
        $shop_page_url = get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) );
        $cart_contents_count = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
        $cart_contents = sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', $cart_contents_count, 'your-theme-slug'), $cart_contents_count);
        $cart_total = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();
        // Uncomment the line below to hide nav menu cart item when there are no items in the cart
        // if ( $cart_contents_count > 0 ) {
            if ($cart_contents_count == 0) {
                $menu_item = '<li class="right"><a class="wcmenucart-contents" href="'. $shop_page_url .'" title="'. $start_shopping .'">';
            } else {
                $menu_item = '<li class="right"><a class="wcmenucart-contents" href="'. $cart_url .'" title="'. $viewing_cart .'">';
            }

            $menu_item .= '<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ';

            $menu_item .= $cart_contents.' - '. $cart_total;
            $menu_item .= '</a></li>';
        // Uncomment the line below to hide nav menu cart item when there are no items in the cart
        // }
        echo $menu_item;
    $social = ob_get_clean();
    return $menu . $social;
}
```

Comment: Where is the JavaScript?

Comment: I am using wordpress

Comment: I get that but the question still stands. You need JS for AJAX (abbreviation of *asynchronous JavaScript and XML*). You have to send a POST request in your JS to send some data to a Woocommerce hook, where is this function?

Answer (score 2):

The idea for using ob_get_clean() is correct but you need to use proper hook which might be `woocommerce_add_to_fragments`.Like you could collect the ajax returned data into a variable using a function like below code updates the cart count--

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'newCount');
function newCount($fr){
    global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    ob_start();
    echo'<a class="cart-contents" href="'.WC()->cart-
>get_cart_url().'">'.WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count().'</a>';
    $fr['a.cart-contents'] = ob_get_clean();
     return $fr;
}
```

then buffer it to your place of display :

```
Cart total: <a class="cart-contents">WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count()</a>
```

PS:You need PHP7 to run above code.

Comment: I tried pasting this code in my functions.php and the cart items and total were not updating when I clicked on "add to cart"

Comment: This only updates total.Use `<a class="cart-contents">...</a>` in your theme file (ex. header.php) and the function in functions.php